# How to test html canvas experiments on Chrome locally

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas

I wrote a simple canvas demo program but it doesn't seem to produce the required result.
Here is my code:-

```
    window.onload = function(){
        var canv = document.getElementById('canv');
        var cxt = canv.getContext('2d');
        if(cxt){
            var myimg = document.getElementById('mypic');
            setTimeout(function(){
                cxt.drawImage(myimg,0,0,canv.width,canv.height);
                var edit = cxt.getImageData(0,0,canv.width,canv.height);
                var imgdata =  edit.data;
                for(var i=0;i<imgdata.length;i+=4){
                    imgdata[i] = 255;
                    imgdata[i++] = 255;
                    imgdata[i+3] = 127;
                }
                cxt.putImageData(imgdata,0,0);
            }
            ,100);
            $('<p>Canvas Created</p>').appendTo('body');
        }
    };
```

Comment: Try outputting a log message to see if ctx is null or not.

Comment: Also, you likely are getting a DOM security error. You should run it from a web server (even if it's just running `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`)

Comment: you can use http://jsfiddle.net/ for tests

Comment: alternately, you could load up a virtual machine with a webserver running (debian+apache or similar), give the vm an address on your local network, and then test that way. this would avoid any errors that arise from getting pages from your own machine.

Comment: @Maz:yeah you're correct i'm getting DOM security error.But is there any work around for testing local files.Also i put this file on my apache local server running on same laptop but still getting no required result

Answer (score 0):

Most likely one of two things is going wrong.

You are not waiting for your image to finish loading which might be a problem.

Or you are running in to a security exception. Calling `getImageData` is now allowed if an image has been loaded on to the canvas from an outside source. Your hard-drive constitutes an outside source, even if you are running locally. To see if this is the case I'd suggest debugging in FireFox because its web console will actually tell you about this security error.

Comment: I'm running into security exception.And i tried it on opera,firefox and chrome but all three are producing same result i.e. drawing the unchanged image on canvas.

Comment: The only workaround you've got for testing local files then is to start up a simple web server. It's a pain I know. You could try running Chrome with a flag: C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files

Comment: I think Simon is right here.  If you're viewing the page on your local file system, you'll encounter a Same Origin problem similar to XHR on a local file system.  Chrome doesn't want a locally loaded page to have any real access to other files or it could send a local file to the server. --allow-file-access-from-files will eliminate this check but put your system at risk.  A local server is best.